# Saving Json multiple data to sqlite database

Tags: android, json, sqlite, data-retrieval

I want to save json data to sqlite database but the problem is that I am a beginner and I don't know how to add json multiple data to sqlite. I want to save this kind of data to sqlite but I don't know how to save and then how to retrieve?

```
{
  car: "Bmw",
  value: 5
},

{
  car: "mercedez",
  value: 2
},

{
  car: "ferrari",
  value: 4
},

{
  car: "civic",
  value: 7
},
```

Comment: study about it from this link https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Comment: I also fell in the same problem and no help